# How to pass value of drop down list to stored procedure in sqlserver in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table:

[image]

and multiplied with final result as follows:

[image]

a procedure is defined as follow to multiply: (it must be multiplied the values of dropdown list with value in database and then sum them horizontally and show resault in final result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cstored]    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   
DECLARE @Ta int
DECLARE @Em int
DECLARE @Ma int
DECLARE @Sa int

SET @Em = 8    >>>> need to be set by user selection in dropdows list
SET @Ta= 6     >>>> need to be set by user selection in dropdows list
SET @Sa= 5     >>>> need to be set by user selection in dropdows list
SET @Ma = 7    >>>> need to be set by user selection in dropdows list

SELECT 
  Namec,
  Tar*@Ta AS val1,
  Emk*@Em as val2,
  Mas*@Ma as val3,
  San*@Sa As val4,
  (Tar*@Ta)+(Emk*@Em)+(Mas*@Ma)+(San*@Sa) as finalresult
FROM Cdetail 
END
```

as you can see above in screen shot it works well in database, but the value has been set manually in. I want it to be set by user selection.

```
SET @Em = 8
```

it was for database , but I created some dropdown in asp web page in order to select value by user as follow :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Em">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ta">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Sa">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ma">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Em">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ta">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Sa">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ma">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Em">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ta">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Sa">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ma">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Em">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ta">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Sa">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="@Ma">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

each dropdown need to have a default value as follow:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 8;
DropDownList2.SelectedValue = 7;
DropDownList3.SelectedValue = 6;
DropDownList4.SelectedValue = 5;
```

it means that the the value which is selected in dropdown 1 , must sent to stored procedure with digit 8 (DD2 digit 7 and so on) and set the variables then multiplied with relevant its value in database.
and after that show value of `finalresult` in a `gridview` from top to down.

I tried with following code but it does not work , i don't know how can i send value of dropdown to store procedure and feed each item based on selection.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 8;
            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = 7;
            DropDownList3.SelectedValue = 6;
            DropDownList4.SelectedValue = 5;

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["carConnectionString"]);
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand scCommand = new SqlCommand("Carstored", sqlCon);
            scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            scCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("????", DropDownList1);
            scCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("????", DropDownList2);
            scCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("????", DropDownList3);
            scCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("????", DropDownList4);
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scCommand))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want, if user select `Emk` in dropdow 1 , `8` number multiplied (X) to the values of all `Emk` in table and if user select `Tar` in dropdow 2 , `7` number multiplied (X) to the values of all `Tar` in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring variables in your stored procedure, declare parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cstored]    
(
    @Ta int,
    @Em int,
    @Ma int,
    @Sa int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    SELECT 
    Namec,
    Tar*@Ta AS val1,
    Emk*@Em as val2,
    Mas*@Ma as val3,
    San*@Sa As val4,
    (Tar*@Ta)+(Emk*@Em)+(Mas*@Ma)+(San*@Sa) as finalresult
    FROM Cdetail 
END
```

Then, in your c# code, do something like this:

```
DataTable dt;
using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["carConnectionString"]))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    using(var scCommand = new SqlCommand("Carstored", sqlCon))
    {
        scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ta", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Em", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ma", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Sa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scCommand))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work , there is an error in StoredProcedure , there is no default value for Dropdown list(DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 8; and etc )

Comment: in 'sda.Fill(dt);' i receive this error (Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32) , 
also, i could not find definition for  default dropdown value ((DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 8;
DropDownList2.SelectedValue = 7;
DropDownList3.SelectedValue = 6;
DropDownList4.SelectedValue = 5; ))

Comment: Values of the dropdownlist are strings (`"@Em", "@Ta" etc`). You need to change them to numbers. Also, IIRC, The SelectedValue property of an ASP.DropDownList is of type `string` so you need to cast to `int`.

Comment: I did it but the result always is same !! i want if user select 'Em' in drop down list , it is only multiply with values of 'Em' in database, and if user select 'Ta' in dropdown the value multiply with values of 'Ta' in database not all

Comment: Then you need a different procedure all together.

Comment: can you please help me in this regards ?

Comment: You should post a new question to explain exactly what you want the stored procedure to do, with sample data as ddl+dml and desired results.